# Sinatra NoMethodError at / undefined method `stylesheet_link_tag' for #

Tags: html, ruby, sinatra, asset-pipeline, nomethoderror

I am currently making an app with sinatra and i've been working for hours to try to implement bootstrap in it, and realizing how much easier it is in rails.

Anyways, when i run the web server and go to /, I see an error relating to the line `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'app', media: 'all' %>` which I put in my app.erb view(the index of my webapp). This line is meant to load an scss file in the assets/stylesheets folder, and the file contains the @import values for bootstrap.

I'm using the sinatra-asset-pipeline gem, and I've set it up correctly according to the instructions on the github page. I've been trying lots of things for the past 4 hours and nothing has worked. Here's the code for the most important files:

**assets/stylesheets/app.scss**:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

**views/app.erb**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Salah Kayali</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'app', media: 'all' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'app' %>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= partial :header %>
  </body>

</html>
```

**app.rb**:

```
require 'sinatra/partial'
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
# set :bind, '0.0.0.0'
require 'sinatra/asset_pipeline'

class App < Sinatra::Base
    register Sinatra::Partial
    configure do
    set :assets_precompile, %w(app.js app.scss *.png *.jpg *.svg *.eot *.ttf *.woff)
    set :assets_css_compressor, :sass
    set :assets_js_compressor, :uglifier
        register Sinatra::AssetPipeline

        if defined?(RailsAssets)
      RailsAssets.load_paths.each do |path|
        settings.sprockets.append_path(path)
      end
    end
  end

  enable :partial_underscores
    set :partial_template_engine, :erb

  get '/' do
    erb :app
  end
  run! if __FILE__ == $0
end
```

**config.ru**:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require
run App
```

**Rakefile**:

```
require 'sinatra/asset_pipeline/task'
require './app'

Sinatra::AssetPipeline::Task.define! App
```

**Gemfile**:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
ruby "2.2.3"

gem 'bundler', '~> 1.10.6'

gem 'sinatra', require: 'sinatra/base'
gem 'sinatra-asset-pipeline', require: 'sinatra/asset_pipeline'

gem 'thin', '~> 1.6.4'

gem 'sass', '~> 3.4.18'

gem 'coffee-script', '~> 2.4.1'

gem 'uglifier', '~> 2.7.2'

gem 'rack-coffee', '~> 1.0.3'

gem 'sinatra-partial'

source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-jquery'
  gem 'rails-assets-bootstrap-sass'
end
```

I hope someone can help, as I really don't know what to do. I'm normally used to rails, where the asset-pipeline already exists and takes care of everything. I'm forcing myself to make this webapp with sinatra, though, so that I can really understand what actually happens when you "automagically" create things with rails.

Here is a link to a screenshot of the error output in my browser: http://puu.sh/ktUIA/1d8396b034.png

Comment: does it really work when you write `<%= partial :header %>  for erb partials? i've always seen and used <%= erb :header %>. btw, why are you trying to pipe rails specific methods?

Comment: Hey man. Yup, it does, but that's because I added a special gem called 'sinatra-partial' which makes using partials a lot easier. You should check it out and check the documentation, as the normal <%= erb :header %> didn't suit my needs, mainly because I like how partials are handled in rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `stylesheet_link_tag` and `javascript_include_tag` are a part of ActionView, one of the gems underlying Rails (i.e. see `ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper`).

According to the `sinatra-asset-pipeline` documentation:

> Now when everything is in place you can use all helpers provided by
>   sprockets-helpers

Looking at a `sprocket-helpers` example you need to do something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= stylesheet_path 'application' %>">
<script src="<%= javascript_path 'application' %>"></script>
```

So what you're looking for is `stylesheet_path` and `javascript_path` rather than `stylesheet_link_tag` and `javascript_include_tag`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solved the problem. I ran into another one though, I hope you can help. It now gives me the error: Sass::SyntaxError at /
File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets. This is really weird, as i have the gem installed (i used rails-assets). I will edit the main post the code from the gemfile.

Comment: Hey @photoionized i'm sorry to bother you but were you able to look at this?

Comment: Looks to me like `bootstrap-sprockets` is from the `bootstrap-sass` project. I don't see it in your Gemfile. Try adding `gem 'bootstrap-sass'` to your Gemfile

Comment: Hey @photoionized thanks, I fixed it. It turned out that the bootstrap-sass gem that I installed from rails-assets.org simply wasn't cutting it, so I installed it from rubygems. I also has to require bundler in the app.rb file. Thanks for helping me solve these problems.